# testing from a common test fixture; inconsistent results

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, sqlite, nunit

I have two test fixtures that have a common parent. Although the tests involve SQLite/NHib type of stuff, which are usually a bit of a at first, there is something I don't understand about NUnit that I'm hoping will help be fix these tests.

The good news is that if I run (via TestDriven.Net) both the subclassed TestFixtures without selecting the common parent, all tests succeed. But if I include the common parent in the run, I get failures (presumably because my NHib session has been disposed or lost it's binding).

Can anyone explain why the two tests succeed on their own but not with 
the parent, and if there is someway to enforce the successful 
behavior?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
public class ActivityTestFixture : GreenQueryOnlySQLiteTestFixture 
{ 
    protected IProjectDao _projectDao; 
    protected IDao<Account> _accountDao; 
    protected override void OnFixtureSetUp() 
    { 
        base.OnFixtureSetUp(); 
        _projectDao = DataFactory.GetProjectDao(_sessionFactoryContext.SessionFactory); 
        _accountDao = DataFactory.GetAccountDao(_sessionFactoryContext.SessionFactory); 
    } 
} 

[TestFixture] 
public class AccountDaoTests : ActivityTestFixture 
{ 
    [Test] 
    public void FindAll_IsEquivalentToSeeds() { 
        IList<Account> found; 
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction()) { 
            found = _accountDao.FindAll(); 
            tx.Commit(); 
        } 
        found.AssertUnsavedValueSequenceEqual(ActivitySubjectSeeds.AllAccounts.ToAr ray()); 
    } 
} 

[TestFixture] 
public class ProjectDaoTests : ActivityTestFixture 
{ 
    [Test] 
    public void FindAll_IsEquivalentToSeeds() 
    { 
        IList<Project> found; 
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction()) 
        { 
            found = _projectDao.FindAll(); 
            tx.Commit(); 
        } 
        found.AssertUnsavedValueSequenceEqual(ActivitySubjectSeeds.Projects.ToArray ()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean common parent in the run? ActivityTestFixture does not seem to have any tests. Or is that one of the strange things about this?

Comment: @Yads - ActivityTestFixture has the common fixture setup for both classes.

Comment: right, but is it the parent you're referring to in the statement "Can anyone explain why the two tests succeed on their own but not with the parent"?

Comment: @Yads. correct, it is the parent I am referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the error that you're getting is, but it's likely because you have some kind of static fields in the `GreenQueryOnlySQLiteTestFixture` class. The way NUnit works is that a fixture lives for the lifetime of the tests inside of it. So it is only created once for all of the tests. This is different from xUnit which lives for the lifetime of one test.

Without seeing the entire implementation it's hard to see what is wrong. However, you can remove the `TestFixtureAttribute` from your parent fixture since it does not appear to have any tests anyway.

Comment: Yes and no, statics are at least part of the problem, but they aren't in the GreenTestFixture; they are in a static DataFactory I am trying to work out, and which is now out of that test fixture hierarchy. It works fine again. There is no attribute on the parent. Cheers